# For an open subset $U\subseteq X\times Y$, is the section $U_x$ open in $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $U$ an open subset of $X\times Y$. For $x\in X$, let $$U_x=\{y\in Y: (x,y)\in U\}$$

Is it $U_x$ an open subset of $Y$?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume the subsets are proper, yes?

Comment: Yes this is not a problem.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: no, I need this to understand a proof.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $$U_x=\{y\in Y:(x,y)∈U\}=\pi_Y(U\cap\{x\}\times Y)$$
where $\pi_Y$ is the projection onto $Y$.
Or, if $\barπ$ denotes the restriction of $π_Y$ to $\{x\}×Y$, then
$U_x=\barπ(U∩\{x\}×Y)$. Can you show that $U∩\{x\}×Y$ is open in $\{x\}×Y$ and that $\barπ$ is a homeomorphism between its domain and $Y$?

Comment: i don't see why $U_x=\bar{\pi}(U)$

Comment: @janmarqz ; Because $\pi_Y(U\cap \{x\}\times Y)=U_x$ and $\bar\pi=\pi_{Y|\{x\}\times Y}$ so $\bar\pi(U)=\pi_Y(U\cap \{x\}\times Y).$

Comment: ok...but, how do you prove  that $\bar{\pi}(U)\subset U_x$?

Comment: @user44319, how do you define $\bar{\pi}$ for $U$ on $U-(\{x\}\times Y)$??

Comment: Dear @janmarqz, $\bar\pi=\pi_{Y|\{x\}\times Y}: \{x\}\times Y \longrightarrow Y. $! $\bar\pi$ is the restriction of $\pi_Y$ to $\{x\}\times Y.$

Comment: to talk about $\bar{\pi}(U)$ you have to define $\bar{\pi}$ for all $U$, not only for $U\cap(\{x\}\times Y)$

Comment: @janmarqz; Yes you right.

Comment: I've edited to make it clearer. Of course with $\barπ(U)$ I meant $\barπ(U∩\{x\}×Y)$. I thought this abuse of notation was okay, as it's clear that in order to apply some function to a subset, you should first restrict this subset to the domain of that function. But you are right that, formally, this notation is not allowed.

Comment: @StefanHamcke, however you got a √ underserved XD

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $U_x=\pi_Y^{-1}(U\cap(\{x\}\times Y))$.

Since $U$ is open in $X\times Y$ there is a basic subset $G$ such that $p\in G\subset U$.

For this basic $G$ there exist two open sets $A\subset X$ and $B\in Y$ respectively, such that
$$G=\pi_X^{-1}A\cap\pi_Y^{-1}B.$$

We will prove that $p\in B\subset U_x$.

For if  $q\in B$ then $(x,q)\in\pi_Y^{-1}B$.
But also $(x,q)\in\pi_X^{-1}A$, since $\pi_X(x,q)=x$.

So $(x,q)\in G$ and hence $(x,q)\in U$.

This proves $p\in B\subset U_x$ and hence $U_x$ is open.

Comment: my proof comes directly from definitions but nothing more, that's elegance, i think

Comment: @user122327, **used**: "$U$ is open in $(X,\tau)$ ifand only if $\forall p\in U\ ,\exists B$ a basic open set in $\tau$ such that $$p\in B\subseteq U".$$

Comment: @janmrqz; Thank you very much   janmarqz.